# Disobedient Div! (Not floating correctly)

Tags: html, css, list, css-float

I am trying to put 2 divs next to each other that contain lists of buttons with another button below both of them but am having problems. I have added float: left to both nav-left and nav-right but nav-right is not next to nav-left? Also the lower button #lower is not staying inside the parent div of #container? Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/fMpBv/1/)

I have tried everything I know to fix this (which is not a lot!) but to no avail. Thank you for any help  : )

Here is the code:

```
#container{width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;}
#nav-left, #nav-right{width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; display: block; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;}
#nav-left{position: relative; float: left;}
#nav-right{position: relative; left: 50%;}
#lower{width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; display: block; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;}
li {list-style: none;}  
ul a, #lower {color: black; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;  background-color: yellow; display: block; margin: 10px; padding: 9px; border: 1px solid black; -moz-border-radius: 12px; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px;}
ul a:hover, #lower:hover {background-color: #fff;} 


<div id="container">
  <ul id="nav-left">
    <li><a href="#">Left Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Left Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Left Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Left Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Left Button</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="nav-right">
    <li><a href="#">Right Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Right Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Right Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Right Button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Right Button</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
  <a id="lower" href="#">Lower Button</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Try reducing the width of the divs. Use the element inspector on Firefox to reduce the width until it displays correctly (right click inspect element)

Comment: Set your widths to 49%

Comment: what if the container is less than 100px wide?

Comment: @ dewd Good Advice, I have never really used Firefox but since reading your post I have just had a play around with it. I think I will de-bug this way in the future...

Comment: @Margate Also get firebug for firefox. This is especially good for debugging javascript `console.log("hello world");` and if you use jquery, add the firequery plugin for firebug. I bet OKCupid developers never stopped using Firefox! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the `border` style attribute. That is why setting the width of each element to 50% is causing the second element to wrap. Setting the width to a smaller amount (like 49%) will fix the problem.

Also, change

`#nav-right{position: relative; left: 50%;}`

to

`#nav-right{position: relative;}`

Comment: Ok I understand. That makes sense and works! I did not think about exceeding the 100% but this is fixed now. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Float pluses +3px to the div,so you have 50% + 50% + extra pixels.(Maybe you should float nav-left to the left and nav-right to the right and set width to the lower value?).That why you have this right-left block issue. And lower button issue fixes with adding width:auto to the ul a, #lower.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I do not often use width: auto as I did not really understand what it did but now I do... Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Three things need to change:
Your divs width should be 49% due to the floats.
Remove the `position:relative;` of your divs also.
To adjust the button just remove `width:100%` from #lower and you're all good.

Here is you **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMpBv/2/)**

Comment: Done! I removed position: relative and width: 100% as per your instructions / fiddle. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have set the width for `#nav_left` and `#nav_right` as 50%. Also you have added 1px border. So each `<div>` will need 2 pixel additional. So you must either 0 the border or reduce the width.
2. You have made both the `<div>` to float left. So `left: 50%` is unnecessary.

Also I see the same kind of problem for your lower button, `a#lower`. This is set to `width: 100%` along with `padding: 9px`, `border: 1px`. This is also overflowing your `#container`.